# SSIS Issue: Stored Procedure Parameters/Variables

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

Using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008.

Using OLE DB Source to OLE DB Destination, I have a stored procedure that has several parameters using specific IDs (e.g. `@BUSINESS_AREA_ID = '32'`). If you would like to bring in all IDs you can use -1 (e.g. `@BUSINESS_AREA_ID = '-1'`).

[OLE DB SOURCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7RP0.png)

[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYlaN.png)

These variables are set up as `VARCHAR(MAX)`. When I run this using `-1` in SQL Server it works completely fine and returns thousands of records, but when I set up the stored procedure in SSIS, it runs very quickly (everything is green) but it writes 0 rows.

I checked the data viewer and there are no return values, so I'm thinking the problem lies with the -1 variable. I have tried setting up the variable using every data type (string, Int32, etc.), using single quotes and not using them, conversion or truncation is not an issue,  etc....I'm stuck. I have set up many more stored procedures and they all work great, but they do not use the -1 feature. Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks all.

Comment: How are you running the stored procedures in SSIS? What component are you using (e.g OLE DB source, etc.)

Comment: Could be a lot of things.   Can you post some screenshots of the SSIS task or component that is calling the stored proc?   Not screenshots of the control flow, but of the properties of that task.

Comment: I'm using OLE DB Source -> Data Conversion  -> OLE DB Destination. Using the data viewer I found no data makes it to the data converter. The "Execution Results" tab shows: [SSIS.Pipeline] Information: "component "OLE DB Destination" (1314)" wrote 0 rows.

Comment: If you send in a positive integer, does it work?

Comment: @BillStuart "... no data makes it to the data converter. ..." What is your source?

Comment: @TabAlleman I've added some screenshots you may find helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: What is `User::Neg_One` set to?

Comment: @EdmundSchweppe it's set as: String, -1

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are passing a string `'-1'` rather than a `-1` int so make sure your variable is set as a string.

[image: string variable BUSINESS_AREA_ID]

Once that is set up, make sure you are correctly mapping the variable to the parameters you are passing to the stored procedure in the `OLE DB Source`. Make sure to follow this format and change the stored procedure, parameter and variable names.

[image: Correct sproc maaping from http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2009/03/05/mapping-stored-procedure-parameters-in-ssis-ole-db-source-editor.aspx]

Comment: Oh, the weirdness of passing parameters in SSIS. While there are no named parameters (in the text), the parameters have to be named (in the dialog box)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I mapped the parameters using the ? and have the parameter names matching. I do not have the Variable names matching the Parameter names, though, since I don't believe that matters. There are absolutely no errors or warnings, it just writes zero rows, which leads be to believe it's not recognizing the negative one in the string. I'll add screenshots to the question now.

Comment: @BillStuart Try calling a dummy stored proc that returns some `SELECT` results with the same `User::Neg_One` variable in the same OLE DB source. Also try recreating the OLE DB Source component.

Answer (score 0):

In the `set query parameters` dialogue, under the `parameters` column, change all the parameter names to:

```
0
1
2
3
etc...
```

and make sure that the variables are assigned to the placeholders in the order that they appear in your query.   In other words, parameter 0 is the first parameter in your query, so assign the appropriate variable to it.